# json marshalling of a complex structure in Golang

Tags: json, go

I just started developing in Golang, and am up against this problem:

I have json data to be accepted by a Golang server.  A sample of one of the fields of this json data is below:

```
 "DATA":[["(610, 658)",1573824148],["(594, 675)",1573824148],["(578,710)",1573824148],["(571, 728)",1573824148],["(552, 769)",1573824148],["(549, 788)",1573824148],["(549, 796)",1573824148]]
```

Note that it is an array of lists, each list being a string and an integer.

I have the following data structures declared:

```
type POINT struct {
    p    string
    t    int
}

type POINTS struct {
    A         int
    B         int
    C         string
    DATA     []FIDGET
}
```

The relevant field is POINTS.DATA which is an array of POINTs. A POINT is a string and an int. To convert from json to Go variables, I use the [encoding/json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package.

My problem is, when I call

```
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &m)
```

I get this error:

```
json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field POINTS.DATA of type main.POINT
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Btw, "body" is the request's body, extracted this way:body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body) where req is the httpRequest.

Comment: You don't have the definition for `FIDGET`, or for the `FIDGETS` show in the error message.